# Confusion regarding Sophomore's dream

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, taylor-expansion, real-numbers

As $x^x$ is defined by $\exp{ (x \ln(x))}$ for $x\neq0$ and the improper integral
$$\int_{0}^{1}x^{x}dx:=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^{+}}\int_{\epsilon}^{1}x^{x}dx.$$
Now $$x^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(x\ln(x))^{n}}{n!}.$$
Hence, by uniform convergence of the series on $(0,\infty)$,
$$\int_{0}^{1}x^{x}dx=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^{+}}\int_{\epsilon}^{1}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(x\ln(x))^{n}}{n!}dx=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^{+}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_{\epsilon}^{1}\frac{(x\ln(x))^{n}}{n!}dx.$$
Now I want to switch the summation and the limit to put in $\int_{\epsilon}^{1}(x\ln(x))^{n}dx$,
but I am confused as to why I can switch them.

Comment: Since $x^x$ is continuously extensible at $0$ with value $1$, I don’t think you need to worry about taking a $\lim_{\varepsilon\to0+}$. You do need to worry about integral-series interchange, but that’s ok here since $x\ln x$ is bounded on this interval and the exponential series converges uniformly

Comment: Then, $\int_0^1 x^n\ln^n(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ can be evaluated with (many ways!) $x=e^{-t}$ and then $u=t(n+1)$, finally using integration by parts or knowledge of the Gamma function to complete